# after selecting the checkbox all listview item checkbox not selected

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

After selecting the header checkbox all listview item checkbox not selected.
Selected listview checkbox items are not moved from list1 to list2. 
Below is the full code
**Home Activity class**

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.AlertDialog;
  import android.content.DialogInterface;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.CheckBox;
  import android.widget.CompoundButton;
  import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeAct extends Activity {

List<DocItem> docDet1 = new ArrayList<DocItem>();
List<DocItem> docDet2 = new ArrayList<DocItem>();
ListView lv1, lv2;
Button btn1;
DocDetAdapter adapter1, adapter2;
int n = 0;
int marksValue;
int value = 0;
CheckBox boxheader;
ArrayList<Boolean> positionArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_act);
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_det1);
    lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_det2);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    boxheader = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxHeader);
    adapter1 = new DocDetAdapter(1);
    adapter2 = new DocDetAdapter(2);
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("1", "john", 20));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("2", "karan", 10));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("3", "james", 5));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("4", "shaun", 60));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("5", "jack", 50));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("6", "sam", 30));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("7", "tony", 6));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("8", "mark", 42));

    lv1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    lv2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    positionArray = new ArrayList<Boolean>(docDet1.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < docDet1.size(); i++) {
        positionArray.add(false);
    }

    boxheader.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                int itemsCount = lv1.getChildCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
                    View view = lv1.getChildAt(i);

                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRow);

                    checkBox.setChecked(true);

                }

            } else {
                int itemsCount = lv1.getChildCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
                    View view = lv1.getChildAt(i);

                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRow);

                    checkBox.setChecked(false);

                }
            }
        }
    });

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int itemsCount = lv1.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
                View view = lv1.getChildAt(i);
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRow);
                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    System.out.println("HomeAct.onCreate(...).new OnClickListener() {...}.onClick() -- 1111  " + i);
                    System.out.println("HomeAct.onCreate(...).new OnClickListener() {...}.onClick() -- 2222  " + docDet1.size());
                    if (docDet1.size() == 1) { 

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeAct.this)
                                .setTitle("Attention!")
                                .setMessage("Last name")
                                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(
                                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {
                                                docDet1.remove(0);
                                                docDet2.add(new DocItem(docDet1.get(0).docNo, docDet1.get(0).name, docDet1.get(0).marks));
                                            }
                                        })
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(
                                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {

                                            }
                                        }).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    docDet2.add(new DocItem(docDet1.get(i).docNo, docDet1.get(i).name, docDet1.get(i).marks));
                    docDet1.remove(i);
                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("HomeAct.onCreate(...).new OnClickListener() {...}.onClick() -- 3333 none are checked ");
                    Toast.makeText(HomeAct.this, "Please select atleast one name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        }
    });

}

DocItem findDocItem(String name) {
    for (DocItem item : docDet2) {
        if (item.name.equals(name)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

DocItem findDocItem2(String name) {
    for (DocItem item : docDet1) {
        if (item.name.equals(name)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
 }

private class DocDetAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int mode; // 1 or 2

    public DocDetAdapter(int mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (mode == 1)
            return docDet1.size();
        else
            return docDet2.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.row_det, null);

        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        TextView tvNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_no);
        TextView tvMarks = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_marks);
        CheckBox box = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRow);
        DocItem invItem;
        if (mode == 1)
            invItem = docDet1.get(position);
        else
            invItem = docDet2.get(position);

        tvNo.setText(invItem.docNo);
        tvName.setText(invItem.name);
        tvMarks.setText(invItem.marks + "");

        box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    positionArray.set(position, true);

                } else {
                    positionArray.set(position, false);
                }
            }
        });
        box.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
  }
 }
```

**DocItem class**

```
public class DocItem {

public String docNo, name;
public Integer marks;

public DocItem(String docNo, String name, Integer marks) {
    super();
    this.docNo = docNo;
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;
    }
  }
```

**home_act.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:ems="3"
    android:text="Add" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="list 1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/row_bg_transparent_white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tv_no"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Sl no"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_marks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:text="Marks"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select all" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_det1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="list 2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_det2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

**row_det.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/v_doc_seperator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/row_bg_transparent_white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Sl no"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_marks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:text="Marks"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please find the below screenshots

If I select header checkbox(select all), only first five rows are selected
[image: 1st]
Remainig rows are not selected

[image: 2nd]

If I select row 2 and row 3 and click on add I got wrong output(refer last screenshot)
[image: 3rd]

row 2 and row 4 are added in list2 (but correct output is row 2 and row 3 should be added) after clicking on add all the checkboxes should be unchecked.
[image: 4th]

Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class HomeAct extends Activity {

List<DocItem> docDet1 = new ArrayList<DocItem>();
List<DocItem> docDet2 = new ArrayList<DocItem>();
ListView lv1, lv2;
Button btn1;
DocDetAdapter adapter1, adapter2;
int n = 0;
int marksValue;
int value = 0;
CheckBox boxheader;
ArrayList<Boolean> positionArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_act);
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_det1);
    lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_det2);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    boxheader = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxHeader);
    adapter1 = new DocDetAdapter(1);
    adapter2 = new DocDetAdapter(2);
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("1", "john", 20));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("2", "karan", 10));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("3", "james", 5));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("4", "shaun", 60));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("5", "jack", 50));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("6", "sam", 30));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("7", "tony", 6));
    docDet1.add(new DocItem("8", "mark", 42));

    lv1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    lv2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    positionArray = new ArrayList<Boolean>(docDet1.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < docDet1.size(); i++) {
        positionArray.add(false);
    }

    boxheader.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                /* int itemsCount = lv1.getChildCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
                    View view = lv1.getChildAt(i);
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRow);
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                } */
                // Update DataSet instead of view
                for (int i = 0; i < docDet1.size(); i++){
                    positionArray.set(i, true);
                }
            } else {
                /* int itemsCount = lv1.getChildCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
                    View view = lv1.getChildAt(i);
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRow);
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                } */
                // Update DataSet instead of view
                for (int i = 0; i < docDet1.size(); i++){
                    positionArray.set(i, false);
                }
            }
            // Update ListView after dataSet updated.
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /* int itemsCount = lv1.getChildCount(); */
            // Get items from end to beginning of list.
            // Otherwise position may be wrong after remove item.
            for (int i = docDet1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                /* View view = lv1.getChildAt(i);
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRow);
                if (checkBox.isChecked()) { */
                if(positionArray.get(i)) {
                    System.out.println("HomeAct.onCreate(...).new OnClickListener() {...}.onClick() -- 1111  " + i);
                    System.out.println("HomeAct.onCreate(...).new OnClickListener() {...}.onClick() -- 2222  " + docDet1.size());
                    if (docDet1.size() == 1) { 
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeAct.this)
                                .setTitle("Attention!")
                                .setMessage("Last name")
                                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(
                                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {
                                                docDet1.remove(0);
                                                docDet2.add(new DocItem(docDet1.get(0).docNo, docDet1.get(0).name, docDet1.get(0).marks));
                                            }
                                        })
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(
                                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {

                                            }
                                        }).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    docDet2.add(0, new DocItem(docDet1.get(i).docNo, docDet1.get(i).name, docDet1.get(i).marks));
                    docDet1.remove(i);
                    /* adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged(); */
                } else {
                    System.out.println("HomeAct.onCreate(...).new OnClickListener() {...}.onClick() -- 3333 none are checked ");
                    Toast.makeText(HomeAct.this, "Please select atleast one name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            // Reset all CheckBox data
            for (int i = 0; i < positionArray.size(); i++){
                positionArray.set(i, false);
            }
            // Update ListViews after all data updated.
            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

DocItem findDocItem(String name) {
    for (DocItem item : docDet2) {
        if (item.name.equals(name)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

DocItem findDocItem2(String name) {
    for (DocItem item : docDet1) {
        if (item.name.equals(name)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
 }

private class DocDetAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mode; // 1 or 2
    public DocDetAdapter(int mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (mode == 1)
            return docDet1.size();
        else
            return docDet2.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.row_det, null);

        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        TextView tvNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_no);
        TextView tvMarks = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_marks);
        CheckBox box = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxRow);

        DocItem invItem;
        if (mode == 1)
            invItem = docDet1.get(position);
        else
            invItem = docDet2.get(position);

        tvNo.setText(invItem.docNo);
        tvName.setText(invItem.name);
        tvMarks.setText(invItem.marks + "");

        box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    positionArray.set(position, true);
                } else {
                    positionArray.set(position, false);
                }
            }
        });

        box.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
}
}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Because after checked you are adding on the array that contain in adapter and on scrolling it will refresh. So you should use **interface** here after checked or unchecked you should add status in main class and then notify your adapter and invalidate your listview.